# Django template includes + extends

Tags: html, django, django-templates

This is my [Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKtkV.png).

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% include 'weapons/head/head.html' %}
{% include 'weapons/body/body.html' %}
</html>
```

body.html:

```
{% load static %}
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'weapons/base/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<span>Hello!</span>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I visit my home.html, it doesn't appear to be working correctly. I see nothing on my page, however the "Hello!" message is expected to be shown. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base `{% block content %}` must be in `base.html` else it won't be usable by `home.html`.

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% include 'weapons/head/head.html' %}
<body>
{% block content %}
{# Leave it empty or add a default content that can be overwritten by other templates #}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks!